# Multiple separate bracketed code segments after a conditional statement

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, brackets

In the following code example - is it bad practice? Also why does the compiler go into the 2nd bracketed statement? I've oddly never experienced this before but it came up in an interview situation. I would have thought the 2nd bracketed segment would look for another conditional statement. The code is as follows:

```
if ( condition )
{
    // some code
}
{
    // some code
}
```

Thank you for any helpful explanations in advance.

Comment: It's just a new scope. There's a [for loop proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3587.pdf) with syntax similar to this, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( condition )
{
    // gets executed if condition == TRUE
}
{
    // always gets executed, has nothing to do with previous if statement
    int a = 42 ; //only exists inside brackets
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a block using `{` and `}` anywhere; it does not need to be attached to an `if` condition.

It can be useful for controlling an object's lifetime.

```
{
    MyObject foo;
    // ... do something with foo ...
}   // MyObject just went out of scope, so its destructor is called
// foo is no longer defined
```